# How to negate "exists" in elastic 5.x filter query?

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering

I have to aggregate filtered data, and the filter should be like such SQL condition:

```
WHERE currency = "USD" AND (
    project in (151515, 161616) 
  OR
    project IS NULL
  )
```

In elastic 5.5 there's no `missing` query, only `exists`, but I can't negate it. How to do it?

```
GET /myindex/mytype/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        }
        {
          "terms": {
            "project": [151515, 161616]
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": { //need to negate `exists` here, how?
              "field": "project"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_month": {
      //... some aggs here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so easily by wrapping the `exists` query in a `bool/should/bool/must_not` query, like this:

```
GET /myindex/mytype/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "project"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "project": [
                    151515,
                    161616
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_month": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: looks this query works not exactly that way I need: it's similar to WHERE project IN (151515,161616) AND project IS NULL            But I need OR there - that's the case. Now your query returns always empty result. Could you please adjust your query to make it correct?

Comment: Sorry, @Val, but this doesn't work as well. Now `should` clause affects document's score in the search result, and doesn't make any effect when is used as `filter` sibling as now. See docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Looks I have to make a complex query inside `filter`. Do you have more ideas how to do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer again. this is the semantic equivalent of your SQL query